# Validate a string with Java Regular expression

Tags: java, regex

In the input String *value* either **n** or **t** or **y** can exist but not more then once.

Same rule is applicable with `*+-`. If exist will occur once. How to achieve with RegEx?

Its a date field which generates date using various shortcut keys like n= now;+1= next day;-1=previous day,y=current day-1;t= now;t+1= current date + 1:00 hrs;t+2= current date + 2:00 hrs. I need to validate the input.

```
private static final String DATE_SHORTCUT_CHARS_ALLOWED = "nt*y+-";

public static void main(String []args){
    String value = "tnt-+";//not ok
    //String value = "t+";//ok
    //String value = "t+-";// not ok
    //String value = "nty+";//not ok
    //String value = "n+n+";//not ok
    //String value = "n++";//not ok
    //String value = "n+";//ok

   if((value.matches(".*([a-zA-Z])\\1{1,}.*")) || (value.matches(".*(\\W)\\1{1,}.*"))){
       System.out.println("not ok"); 
   }else{
        System.out.println("ok");
   }
 }
```

Comment: It seems to me you just need [`s.matches("[nty][*+-]|[*+-][nty]")`](https://regex101.com/r/mcOfdZ/1). Or can you have inputs like `ABCD .... n+` that should be matched?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, but it will not work for String value = "n";

Comment: Ok, what about [`s.matches("(?:[nty][*+-]?|[*+-][nty]?)?")`](https://regex101.com/r/mcOfdZ/2) (this will also match an empty string)?

Comment: you could try this also  `^([nty][*+-]|[*+-][nty]|[nty]|[*+-])$` @Wiktor this wont match any empty string though.

Comment: @ShafinMahmud: Didn't I mention it does? The question is unclear. *can exist* does not mean *must exist*. That is why I am suggesting this or that to make OP post the *real*, comprehensive requirements. Without them, there can't be a correct answer to the question.

Comment: @KoushikMallik: Please add the relevant details to the question: 1) should the string consist of a single letter `n`, `t`, or `y` or any 1 symbol from your set, or can it contain other chars (if yes, what chars? How many?) 2) can the string be empty?

Comment: 1.The string can not be empty already handled.

Comment: @KoushikMallik So, `s.matches("[nty][*+-]?|[*+-][nty]?")` works, right? See [**this Java demo**](http://ideone.com/xxbz4T).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I don't think we will be able to achieve it with regex because the logic is bit weird .The length of the input is not fixed.
The First character of the value must be any one from the list "nt*y+-".

The second character may or may not be available.
If available the second Character can be * + - (If the first char is n t or y).
If the first char is * + - then no repetation allowed(i.e * + - are not permitted).Second char will be a number [0-9].

Third char can also exist.Will be a number.

Comment: No, because you do not share exact requirements. No requirements - no solution, because any code works or does not work as per the requirements. Once you define them and **put into the question body**, someone will come up with a suggestion.

Comment: Its a date field which generates date using various shortcut keys like n= now;+1= next day;-1=previous day,y=current day-1;t= now;t+1= current date + 1:00 hrs;t+2= current date + 2:00 hrs. I need to validate the input.